# Create instance of a type in another domain

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm reading a code which is creating an instance of a type in another Domain by reflection. Why do we need to do this? What is the advantages of this kind of instance creation?

```
AppDomain _domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("ServerImporterDomain");
var type = typeof (ServerImporter);
ServerImporter si = _domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(type.Assembly.FullName, type.FullName) as ServerImporter;
```

Comment: You haven't posted the real code which executes in another appdomain. There will be a call to `domain.DoCallback` I believe, post that also. If not, follow the `_domain` variable to see for what it is used for.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Is the code of ServerImporter class important for this question? There is no use for _domain, it is just used si for call some of its methods.

Comment: You asked *What is the advantages of this code?* answer is nothing unless there's something really going inside the constructor of `ServerImporter`. Just creating the instance alone is not useful, show us how it is used and what kind of code it executes inside it?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: No,sorry, I mean what is the advantages of creating an instance in another domain. Ryan Said some of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some reasons for this would be:

- Security sandboxing. The app domain that you create can run at a lower trust level than the main application. This doesn't seem to be the case here as you are not passing an AppDomainSetup to the CreateDomain call.
- Memory management. If a given assembly requires large amounts of memory and you know that you only need to use that assembly for a short time, you can load it into its own domain and then unload it when you're done with it.
- Different domains can handle uncaught exceptions differently and have different ProcessExit handlers.

A good writeup is at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cclayton/archive/2013/05/21/understanding-application-domains.aspx.

Comment: I waited until now if there is another answer .I accept your answer as best answer. Thank you again  :)